# JavaScript: Somehow my var n from input gets multiplied by 10 I have no idea where it happens

Tags: javascript, arrays, button, input

I have been doing a fibo function for practicing and suddenly I get the n number acquired form the input field always multiplied by 10. So if I type 1 will calculate 11 numbers from fibo sequence if I type 2 will do 21 numbers and so on.. Does someone spot where is the mistake?

```js
function fibo(){
 var n = document.getElementById("numb").value;
 console.log(n);
 var r=[];
 var i;
 if (isNaN(n) || n < 1 || n > 10) {
    document.getElementById("ex1").innerHTML = "Input not valid";
    } else {
     for (i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
      console.log(i);
      console.log(r);
   if (i == 0){

    r[i] = i;

   }
   else if (i == 1){

    r[i] = i;

   }
   else{

    r[i] = r[i - 1] + r[i - 2];
    
   }
    }
    document.getElementById("ex1").innerHTML = r.toString();
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Fibonacci</h2>

<p>Please input a number between 1 and 10:</p>

<input id="numb">
<button type="button" onclick="fibo()">Calculate Fibo</button>
<p id="ex1"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where's the code? most likely you need to add `n + Number(input.value)`  instead of `n + input.value`

Comment: How can we possibly spot the mistake in your code if you didn't post your code?

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of Stack Overflow and read how to add the [required code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why do you think 2*10 is 21? Looks like you're adding the number as a string to the 1. So I guess if you enter 5 you will end up with 51?!

Comment: There is the code I forgot to post you guys are quick!

Answer (score 0):

I just had to remove the "+1" in the for loop. Thanks anyway.

```js
function fibo(){
 var n = document.getElementById("numb").value;

 var r=[];
 var i;
 if (isNaN(n) || n < 1 || n > 10) {
    document.getElementById("ex1").innerHTML = "Input not valid";
    } else {
     for (i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
     
   if (i == 0){

    r[i] = i;

   }
   else if (i == 1){

    r[i] = i;

   }
   else{

    r[i] = r[i - 1] + r[i - 2];
    
   }
    }
    document.getElementById("ex1").innerHTML = r.toString();
 }
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Fibonacci</h2>

<p>Please input a number between 1 and 10:</p>

<input id="numb">
<button type="button" onclick="fibo()">Calculate Fibo</button>
<p id="ex1"></p>

<script src="fibo.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```